# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-1}^1(5x^4-4x^3)\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1: One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

> *Page 83. Exercise 8.* Compute $$\int_{-1}^1(5x^4-4x^3)\mathrm dx.$$

*My solution.* $$\int_{-1}^1(5x^4-4x^3)\mathrm dx=5\int_{-1}^1x^4\mathrm dx-4\int_{-1}^1x^3\mathrm dx=\left.5\frac{x^5}{5}\right|_{-1}^1-\left.4\frac{x^4}{4}\right|_{-1}^1=2-0=2.$$

But, solution in book's answer page is $0$, this looks like pretty simple integral, so have I missed anything or is there a typo in the book?

Comment: your result is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is indeed $2$ and probably there's a typo in the book. Your solution is correct.

As you can see from the graph of $f(x) = 5x^4 - 4x^3$ there is no way the integral can be $0$:
$\hspace{11em}$[image: plot]